# How can the Telnet service on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS be enabled?

Tags: 14.04, server, services, telnet

How can I enable the Telnet service on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS?
Can somebody include a detailed description about the needed packages and configurations?

Comment: I succeeded with this tutorial, http://jdav.is/2018/04/22/installing-and-enabling-telnet-server-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 17):

> Please do note, that using **Telnet** is insecure because the communication is not encrypted, your
> passwords and all other data will be transmitted as clear texts. Use **Secure Shell (SSH)** instead avoiding Telnet.

---

**To Enable Telnet**

Install the Telnet server with

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

The service should be fired-up automatically once the installation is done. Your may also check the service status if required using;

```
sudo systemctl status xinetd
```

**To Telnet an IP**

```
telnet serverip
```

If you would like to change its ports, you'll need to edit `/etc/services` with the line;

```
telnet        23/tcp
```

Once changed, restart to apply the changes with;

```
sudo systemctl restart xinetd
```

**More info:** [Install and Enable Telnet server in Ubuntu Linux](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: xinetd status says "0 available services" after running the apt-get command

Comment: You need to add the telnet service to /etc/inetd.conf. Look at http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 6):

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

The Telnet service is started automatically once the installation is done. And you can either run `telnet serverip` or use a Telnet client (PuTTy, SecureCRT, etc.) to access this server.

To change the port (default is 23), edit the /etc/services file with your favorite text editor. Find out and change the number in the line below:

```
telnet        23/tcp
```

To apply changes, you have to restart the service by running the command below:

```
sudo systemctl restart xinetd
```

**Telnet is insecure because the communication is not encrypted, your password and all other data will be transmitted as clear text. If possible avoid Telnet, and use Secure Shell (SSH) instead.**

reference [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/enable-telnet-ubuntu-14-04/)

Further you may refer [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux)