# unable to telnet the ubuntu from windows host

Tags: networking, telnet

i have ubuntu 16.4 as Host  with IP 192.168.56.1 and Windows 7 as guest inside Virtualbox have IP 192.168.5.101 and the adapter mode is host-only , the host and guest can contact each other on Ping command .
the Host can telnet and Curl the  guest but the reverse is not working .
the error message tell me that the connection failed on port 23  , i have test new port the same issue .
i have disabled the firewall on Host and Guest  also the AV on Guest .
i have enabled the telnet on the Host and Guest .
i know that the telnet is not secure but fro some reason  i want do that .

Comment: Telnet is the client software, did you enable `telnetd` (the server) on your intended server?    It probably needs installing, as by default its disabled if not uninstalled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/668725/how-can-the-telnet-service-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts-be-enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring telnet on my new Ubuntu VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033661/configuring-telnet-on-my-new-ubuntu-vm)

Comment: Do not use telnet. There's *zero* reason not to use ssh. It's more capable, and secure.

Comment: i enabled the telnetd