# How to enable telnet server

Tags: 18.04, telnet

I followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668725/how-can-the-telnet-service-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts-be-enabled) but when doing `telnet localhost` or `telnet localhost 23`, getting `unable to connect to remote host: connection refused`.
I also shut down firewall: `sudo ufw disable`.

When doing `sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd status` I get active (running)

I can do `telnet` to the internet e.g. `telnet google.com 80` (I know this is `telnet` client)

More information: version 18.04.1 TLS, running on **Oracle VM VirtualBox**.

Comment: Is your machine at  home network or corporate network ?

Answer (score 6):

Create following file:

```
vi /etc/xinetd.d/telnet
```

content:

```
service telnet
{
disable = no
flags = REUSE
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

restart service. I think this does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem like this after following ( http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux ) 
but I saw an error `/var/adm/syslog`:

```
 xinetd[11406]: execv( /usr/sbin/tcpd ) failed: No such file or directory (errno = 2)
```

Problem solved by installing tcpd

```
sudo apt-get install tcpd
```

Comment: thanks it solve my issue after wasted so much time to find solution.